# Passing array of arrays with getParcelableArrayList to several instances of a same fragment

Tags: arraylist, fragment, bundle

I have a TabLayout with a fragment in each tab. The first tab is a fragment instance, and the next has an instance of the same fragment:

```
adapter.addFragment(fragmentoFichaSerie.newInstance(ficha, cookie), "Ficha");
        for (HTMLParser.temporada objTemporada : ficha.temporadas)
        {
         adapter.addFragment(fragmentoCapitulos.newInstance(objTemporada.capitulos, cookie), objTemporada.nombre);
        }
```

"ficha.temporadas" contains "n" "capitulos" arrays. Each fragment receive one "capitulos" array.

fragmentoCapitulos contains a RecyclerView that i populate with an ArrayList of objects (each item get its data from one array's position).

In the fragment, i receive the array in the "newInstance" method and put it in a bundle with putParcelableArrayList.

```
public static fragmentoCapitulos newInstance(List<HTMLParser.capitulo> capitulos, String Cookie) {
        fragmentoCapitulos fragment = new fragmentoCapitulos();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelableArrayList("capitulos", (ArrayList<HTMLParser.capitulo>) capitulos);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        cookie = Cookie;
        return fragment;
    }
```

In onCreateView i get the content of the bundle:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.capitulos, container, false);

        RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recCapitulos);
        TextView empty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.empty);
        ImageView imgEmpty = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgEmpty);

        ArrayList<HTMLParser.capitulo> capitulos;
        capitulos = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("capitulos");
```

My problem is if i'm in tab 2, i should receive the first array of "ficha.temporadas", but i receive the second array (the first tab contains another fragment that doesn't need any array).

I try to pass a void array to the first tab but doesn't work. What can i do to pass the correct array to each fragment?

Comment: I don't undestand what's going on. Instead of using ParcelableArrayList to get "capitulos" subarray, i use the selected tab to get it from main array. I verified in debug that i'm receiving the correct subarray, however i don't see in the screen this subarray when the recycler is filled. I receive a subarray but i see another. Some cache or refresh problem? I'm confused and i don't know what can i do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution. I was wrong with the problem, not a parcelable error.

When viewpager creates pages dynamically always generates pages at both sides of current page. This was doing incorrectly. After debuging much time and reading a lot of articles, i changed FragmentPagerAdapter by FragmentStatePagerAdapter and all works fine.

I hope this could be helpful for someone with same problem.